# Optimise query to determine of a value is between a min and max value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with a min and max field. The table is filled with 200 records that all contain a range from those min and max values. I need to determine if a given value is in one of those ranges.

**Example**

```
min | max    
21  | 34    
64  | 83    
112 | 134
```

Given value: 36. In this case the query shouldn't find anything.

Of course, I can loop through every record and query if the value is between those values, but the query will run a couple of times per minute, so I'd like to know how to optimise this.

Comment: What indexes do you have on this table?

Comment: a) What does your query currently look like? b) Have you benchmarked it against a reasonable live data set to determine its performance? c) I believe questions on optimisation are supposed to go on codereview.stackexchange.com rather than here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how RDBMS works - it iterates through rows. 200 records is actually nothing for modern databases.

Anyway to optimize this, you should create an index on these columns.
**One** index on **two** columns.

Then simple query like below will use this index and work very fast even with a lot of rows.

```
SELECT * from table where 36 between min and max;
```

Comment: +1 for "200 records is actually nothing for modern databases"

Answer (score 0):

Creating an index on both the min and max columns should improve the performance

Answer (score 0):

The between operator does what you need:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 36 BETWEEN min AND max;
```

Answer (score 0):

An index on both columns does not particularly help.  The query you are looking for is:

```
select *
from minmax 
where "min" <= 36 and "max" >= 36;
```

Unfortunately, this has two inequalities; an index can really only take advantage of one of the inequalities.  So, having `"max"` in the index *does* help a little bit, but only because the index "covers" the query.  That is, the index can be used for processing the query, with no reference to the original data pages.

However, with only 200 rows in the table, the processing is not particularly onerous.  If you want to know if something exists in the table, I would suggest this query:

```
select (case when exists (select 1 from minmax where "min" <= 36 and "max" >= 36)
             then 1
             else 0
        end)
```

My guess is that the performance of this on such a small table is pretty much the same with an index on `minmax(min)` or `minmax(min, max)`.  For a large table, the composite index would be better.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very similar problem to [GeoIP table join with table of IP's in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195304/geoip-table-join-with-table-of-ips-in-mysql). It is common for people to look up GeoIP information in a MySQL table and the fastest way to do this is using a Spatial index.

The basic is idea is to create a polygon with your data that incorporates the minimum and maximums in your table, then add a spatial index to this field. Finally using `MBRCONTAINS()` you can very quickly and efficiently see if a point is inside a set.

Here is an article describing how to do this: http://blog.jcole.us/2007/11/24/on-efficiently-geo-referencing-ips-with-maxmind-geoip-and-mysql-gis/

The basic idea is to create a polygon like:

```
SET poly = GEOMFROMWKB(POLYGON(LINESTRING(
    POINT(min,-1),
    POINT(max,-1),
    POINT(max,1),
    POINT(min,1),
    POINT(min,-1)
)));
```

Then to lookup use

```
SELECT id
FROM your_table
WHERE MBRCONTAINS(ip_poly, POINTFROMWKB(POINT([SEARCH_NUMBER], 0)))
```