# limit 1 in joined table?

Tags: mysql, join, limit

### tables

- `ip2country` has 250k rows (ip ranges inserted by ascending from_ip)
- `sessions` has 50 rows

obvious and slow (2.687 sec):

```
SELECT
  s.*,
  ip.country
FROM
  sessions s
  JOIN ip2country ip ON s.ip_addr BETWEEN ip.from_ip AND ip.to_ip
```

while this by itself is fast (0.031 s):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  ip2country
WHERE
  from_ip >= 387703808
LIMIT 1
```

So essentially the question comes down to being able to use the LIMIT within the joined table. Can this be done, and what would it look like? (MySQL 5.7.24)

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: LIMIT is done post table scanning. It won't have any real effect. Do you have proper indexes setup in your tables? Try using EXPLAIN on the first statement

Comment: yeah, indexes are there, but they don't help at all. EXPLAIN doesn't look great :(

1 SIMPLE s  ALL ip_addr    48 100.00 
1 SIMPLE ip  ALL to_ip,from_ip    248160 11.11 Range checked for each record (index map: 0x6)

Comment: hmm, this isn't looking great: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195304/geoip-table-join-with-table-of-ips-in-mysql

Comment: very ungood: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/ip-range-table-performance/. looks like i'm stuck with adding a "geo" column and tagging records in the sessions table with the PKs from ip2country during insertion. a sad, but fast and least convoluted "solution", indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a similar example:

I have a table with 100 IPs (32-bit integers) and a table with 1M IP ranges. (See schema and sample data below.)

The following query is similar to yours:

```
select *
from ips i join ip_ranges r
  on i.ip between r.ip_from and r.ip_to
```

It takes 9.6 seconds to return 100 IPs with the corresponding range. That are 100 ms per IP. If I just search for a single IP

```
select *
from ip_ranges r
where 555555555 between ip_from and ip_to
```

It takes like 100 ms (as expected). Note that I will get a result in "zero" time for IP = 1 but will wait 200 ms for IP = 999,999,999. So 100 ms is an average.

Adding `LIMIT 1` doesn't help here. But in combination with `ORDER BY ip_from DESC` I get the results in "zero time".

Now I could try to run one `LIMIT 1` per IP in a subquery:

```
select i.ip
, (
    select ip_from
    from ip_ranges r
    where i.ip between r.ip_from and r.ip_to
    order by r.ip_from desc
    limit 1
) as ip_from
from ips i
```

But MySQL (5.6 in my case) is making a poor job here, and it takes 13 seconds to execute.

So all we can do, is to fetch all IPs and execute one query per IP. This at least will be faster than 10 seconds.

Another way is to generate a UNION ALL query with one subquery per IP. You can do it either in your application or directly in SQL with dynamic prepared statements:

```
set @subquery = '(
    select {ip} as ip, r.*
    from ip_ranges r
    where {ip} between ip_from and ip_to
    order by ip_from desc
    limit 1
)';

set session group_concat_max_len = 1000000000;

set @sql = (select group_concat(replace(@subquery, '{ip}', ip) separator 'union all') from ips);

prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
```

This query executes in less than 1ms.

#### Test schema and dada

```
create table ips(
    ip int unsigned primary key
);

insert into ips(ip)
    select floor(rand(1) * pow(10, 9))
    from seq1m s
    limit 100
;


create table ip_ranges(
    ip_from int unsigned not null,
    ip_to   int unsigned not null,
    primary key (ip_from, ip_to)
);

insert into ip_ranges
    select (s.seq - 1) * 1000 as ip_from
         , s.seq * 1000 - 1   as ip_to
    from seq1m s
    limit 1000000
;
```

`seq1m` is a table with 1M sequence numbers. You can create it with

```
create table seq1m (seq int auto_increment primary key);
insert into seq1m (seq)
    select null
    from information_schema.COLUMNS a
       , information_schema.COLUMNS b
    limit 1000000;
```

Comment: thanks for the thorough answer. i decided to simply tag the record at same time as session init/insertion with the PK of the ip range. it makes the code simpler and more obvious and is essentially free. `INSERT INTO sessions (key, ip_addr, ip_range_id) SELECT 'abc123', '128.55.64.25', id FROM ip_ranges r WHERE inet_aton('128.55.64.25') <= r.max LIMIT 1` (ip_ranges is already naturally ordered ASC).

Comment: Your solution looks good. I guess/hope you have an index starting with `r.max`. I would though add `ORDER BY r.max ASC` - so you don't relay on implementation details.